# Trying to get multiple values from a multiplication using a list with python

Tags: python, range, multiplication

I am trying to include a list (with the use of a range) within a multiplication to get multiple values back:

say I have `z = range(0, 26, 5)`

how do I include this range into  the formula:

```
t = (z * 4) + z
```

to then get back five different values? (i.e for every value of z)

Comment: `[(num * 4) + num for num in range(0, 26, 5)]`?

Comment: Python does not support vectorization for this kind of operation, but `numpy` does. If you're not using `numpy`, try the solution from the previous comment.

Comment: What's the expected output here? Do you expect ``t`` to have 6 or 36 elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for-loop over the range within square-brackets, which will get you a list. This is called a list comprehension.

```
t = [(x * 4) + x for x in z]
```

Isn't that the same as? :

```
t = [(x * 5)  for x in z]
```

Comment: yeah that worked a treat, thanks. The actual formula was more complicated so wanted to demonstrate that I was using z more than once without making the formula more complicated.